# Why is my graphic sometimes centering using a relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've been having an issue which is extremely odd to me. The graphic I'm using is sometimes centered, for reasons I can't understand, but only on certain displays. The top graphic is the bad example, the bottom one is the one I'd like to have. It seems to not be Android version dependent, both the good and bad were replicated on Android 1.6, and the bad was replicated on 2.1. It seems to only be size dependent...

[image: Bad version]

[image: Good level layout]

relevant XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" ads:adSize="BANNER" 
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ></com.google.ads.AdView>
    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_pad android:id="@+id/numberpad" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_pad>
    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar android:id="@+id/Score_Bar" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo_image" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Score_Bar" 
        android:layout_above="@id/numberpad" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/level_logo" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:gravity="left"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/number_select" 
        android:layout_above="@id/numberpad"
        android:layout_below="@id/Score_Bar"
        android:text="0" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/numberSelect" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_viewer android:id="@+id/numberviewer" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Score_Bar"></pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_viewer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I've clearly set the gravity of the image to left, told it to align with Parent left, yet for some unknown reason it wants to align center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the question by a bit of trickery that I had to put in for a different reason. It works, however, to solve two problems with one stone.

Basically, my ImageView became this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/logo_image" 
    android:layout_below="@id/Score_Bar" 
    android:layout_above="@id/numberpad" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/level_logo" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/number_select" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:gravity="left"></ImageView>
```

The key bit was the line `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/number_select"`, forced the image to not overlap with the textView with the number. It's not perfectly to the left, but they at least don't overlap, so I'm saying good enough for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try this code,, 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:ads = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
       android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
       android:layout_height = "fill_parent">

   <RelativeLayout android:id = "@+id/1stRLayout" 
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id = "@+id/adView" 
        ads:loadAdOnCreate = "true" 
        ads:adSize = "BANNER" 
        ads:adUnitId = "@string/admob_unit_id" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
  </RelativeLayout>


  <RelativeLayout android:id = "@+id/2ndRLayout" 
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_above = "@id/1stRLayout"
        android:gravity = "center">

    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_pad android:id = "@+id/numberpad" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
    </pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_pad>  
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout android:id = "@+id/3rdRLayout"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "70dp"
        android:layout_above = "@id/2ndRLayout">

    <ImageView android:id = "@+id/logo_image" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:src = "@drawable/level_logo" 
        android:layout_marginLeft = "8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
        android:layout_marginTop = "6dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:id = "@+id/number_select" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:text = "0"  
        style = "@style/numberSelect" 
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true">
    </TextView>

    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_viewer android:id = "@+id/numberviewer" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginRight = "8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_marginTop = "6dp">
    </pearsonartphoto.AJEG.number_viewer>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout android:id = "@+id/4thRLayout"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop = "true">

    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar android:id = "@+id/Score_Bar" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent">
    </pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar>
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your definition of the ImageView's layout `layout_above="@+id/numberpad` you may run into issues, as you defined it as `numberviewer` below. The above code should solve that.

Only use the `@+id` when defining a layout. Else use `@id`.

Also when defining a layout position within a `RelativeLayout` you should consider to place the elements that are located relative to other elements at the bottom of your layout file.

You can also use `layout_alignParentTop`, `layout_alignParentLeft`, `layout_alignParentRight` or `layout_alignParentBottom` when layouting absolute items within a `RelativeLayout`. You should definately do that in your case.

Comment: I didn't post the entire XML code to begin with, I guess I should have done that... Sigh. Anyways, I'm posting the whole thing now.

Comment: Still, the @+id defines a new id that might not actually exist within your layout, thus generating an error source.

Comment: I've removed +id references except for the android:id, but it still has the same problem. alignParentLeft still has the same problem too...